# Concatenating a list of dataframes into a single dataframe results in NaN values

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

I am pulling a bunch of tables off of a website. I have been able to get a list of dataframes, each dataframe corresponding to a table on the website. However when I try to concatenate them onto one dataframe, the values of the 1st table are there as they should be but the values of the other tables are all NaN besides the column indexes. Code being:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

res = requests.get("https://www.atptour.com/en/players/rafael-nadal/n409/fedex-atp-win-loss")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all(class_="mega-table")


all_data = []
data = pd.read_html(str(table[0]), header =None, index_col= 0)
data = data[0].dropna(axis=0, thresh = 4)
all_data.append(data)

for i in range(1,len(table)):
    data = pd.read_html(str(table[i]), header =None, index_col= 0, skiprows= 0)
    data = data[0].dropna(axis=0, thresh = 4)
    data.columns = [all_data[0].columns]
    all_data.append(data)
print(all_data)
df = pd.concat(all_data)
print(df)
```

:[list of dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWkma.png)
[concatenated dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqCVE.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What result are you expecting? These DataFrames seem to have wildly different columns, I don't think it makes much sense to concatenate them.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Well I would like the columns in each of the dataframes to be under the given headers in the concatenated dataframe. the individual headers for each dataframe are arbitrary. the header of the first dataframe is the one i want. so for example, the first column in the pressure points dataframe would fall under the YTD W/L ,and so forth. if that makes sense. basically taking the values in each of the dataframes and putting them in the concatenated dataframe. sorry for the poor explanation

Comment: also, each individual dataframe has 5 columns

Comment: I think the problem might be that the headers for each dataframe are different

Comment: Ah yes you're right. I just checked again and the data is indeed similar, so the only issue is the column names.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile So now I've formatted each of the dataframes to have the same column names, but now I am getting an error in the concatenation "TypeError: Expected tuple, got str"

Comment: Could you update your post with the new code? I'm currently working on the same thing.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Just did, thanks a lot for your help by the way!

Comment: No problem, it's my pleasure :)

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea why the columns names are so different, yet the data format is ostensibly the same?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It was just the format of the table on the website, but if you look at my updated code, I have changed the column names of each dataframe to be the same!

Comment: Alright, that'll work.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Concatenation still not working though.

Comment: Are the column names of the first DataFrame the best, or was that just an arbitrary choice? What are your preferred column names?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes the column names of the first dataframe are the best!

Comment: What result are you getting from concatenation?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I'm not getting a result from the concatenation anymore. I'm getting an the error 'TypeError: Expected tuple, got str'. I thought it was due to each dataframe having an axis name but that was the case because i got rid of it and tried to concatenate but am getting the same error

Comment: I just posted some code as an answer, take a look! it seems to be working

Comment: I have a few ideas that could make this better, i'll work on them in a bit or tomorrow

Comment: Oops i just realized I messed up the row labels, nevermind

Comment: So yeah as I had mentioned I will only be able to complete my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Quick question for you. I'm working on the code a bit more, and was wondering if it would make sense to replace the NaN values in the `Titles` columns by 0. My guess  is that those values are NaN because they haven't won a Title, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas dataframe concat is giving unwanted NA/NaN columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855777/pandas-dataframe-concat-is-giving-unwanted-na-nan-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will edit this in a bit to include actual explanations, and there are still some changes to be made.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

col_names = ['YTD W/L', 'YTD Fedex Index', 'Career W/L', 'Career Fedex Index', 'Titles']

res = requests.get("https://www.atptour.com/en/players/rafael-nadal/n409/fedex-atp-win-loss")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, features='lxml')

all_tables = soup.find_all(class_='mega-table')

all_data = []

for curr_table in all_tables:
    curr_data = pd.read_html(str(curr_table), header=None, index_col=0)[0]
    curr_data = curr_data[curr_data.iloc[:, 0] != '-']
    curr_data.rename(columns=dict(zip(curr_data.columns, col_names)), inplace=True)
    curr_data = curr_data.astype(dtype={'Titles': 'Int64'})
    all_data.append(curr_data)

res_df = pd.concat(all_data, sort=False, ignore_index=True)

pprint.pprint(res_df)
```

Final output:

```
   YTD W/L  YTD Fedex Index Career W/L  Career Fedex Index  Titles
0   51 - 6            0.895  970 - 196               0.832      84
1   24 - 2            0.923   271 - 38               0.877      19
2   22 - 2            0.917   384 - 79               0.829      35
3   10 - 4            0.714  236 - 150               0.611     NaN
4    7 - 4            0.636   169 - 89               0.655     NaN
5    4 - 1            0.800    84 - 37               0.694     NaN
6    4 - 2            0.667   159 - 73               0.685     NaN
7    1 - 0            1.000    22 - 12               0.647     NaN
8   21 - 3            0.875   436 - 39               0.918      59
9    5 - 1            0.833    71 - 20               0.780       4
10  25 - 2            0.926  461 - 131               0.779      21
11   0 - 0            0.000      2 - 6               0.250       0
12   4 - 0            1.000    82 - 37               0.689       2
13  47 - 6            0.887  888 - 159               0.848      82
14  49 - 1            0.980   858 - 45               0.950     NaN
15   2 - 5            0.286  112 - 151               0.426     NaN
16  46 - 6            0.885  869 - 181               0.828     NaN
17   5 - 0            1.000   101 - 15               0.871     NaN
```

Comment: Thats awesome, the only thing is that I need the row indexes to be that of those in the individual dataframes. Not sure if that was something you were referring to as changes to be made. Thanks again!

Comment: @SanHaKim yeah thats definitely one of the changes, can’t believe i missed it lol

Comment: Hi, I just figured out the row name thing. THANK YOU so much, I really appreciate it. Is there a way for me to give you upvotes or something?

Comment: @SanHaKim That’s sweet lol. You can accept my answer, although it is still really incomplete. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for information on voting and accepting answers.